# Violación de segmento (`core' generado) c++ POO

Tags: c++, poo

*Estoy intentado implementar y aprender las dstintas Estructuras dinamicas, como listas, pilas, colas y arboles. pero estoy estancado en la class principal para aprender estructuras dinamicas, que es la del nodo enlazado simple.
creo una plantilla de nodo, pero luego que instancio no puedo inicializar un puntero de tipo nodo.
Este es mi cogido, es tan minusculo que no logro ver el error.

No le presten atencion a las lineas siguientes de este parrazo. no tiene nada que ver con mi problema, solo que si no agrego mas informacion stackoverflow no me permite publicar mio pregunta. stackoverflow si es molesto con la descripcion del problema, no me permite montar la pregunta si no tengo mayor descripcion, pero el codigo es tan sencillo que habla por si solo, por esta razon sigo narrando mi incomodida con el blog que sigue pidiendo que agregue mas descipcion.*

**nodo.h**

```
#ifndef NODO_H
#define NODO_H

namespace nodo_h{
    template<typename T>
    class Nodo{
        
        public:
            Nodo();
            ~Nodo();
            
            void setDato( T );
            T getDato() const;
            
            void setNext(Nodo *);
            Nodo *getNodo() const;
            
        private:
            
            T dato;
            Nodo *next;      
    };
    
    template< typename T>
    Nodo<T>::Nodo(){
        this->next = new Nodo<T>();
    }
    template< typename T>
    Nodo<T>::~Nodo(){}

    template< typename T>
    void Nodo<T>::setDato(T dato){
        this->dato = dato;
    }
    template< typename T>
    void Nodo<T>::setNext(Nodo* next){
        this->next = next;    
    }
    template< typename T>
    T Nodo<T>::getDato() const{
        return this->dato;
    }

    template< typename T>
    Nodo<T> *Nodo<T>::getNodo() const{
        return this->next;
    }
}

#endif /* NODO_H */
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "nodo.h"
using namespace nodo_h;
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    Nodo<int> *q = new Nodo<int>();
    
    q->setDato(int(1500));
    
    //cout << q.getDato() << endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

**copilador g++**

`estructuras_dinamicas$ ./main`

`Violación de segmento (core' generado)`

Answer (score 2):

Esta línea:

```
Nodo<int> *q = new Nodo<int>();
```

Reserva una pequeña cantidad de memoria e invoca al constructor por defecto de `Nodo`

```
Nodo<T>::Nodo(){
    this->next = new Nodo<T>();
}
```

Que crea otro nodo, es decir, se vuelve a reservar una pequeña cantidad de memoria y se vuelve a invocar el constructor por defecto de Nodo ... y así indefinidamente hasta que tu equipo se quede sin memoria...

No puedes hacer en el constructor una llamada recursiva de este tipo. De hecho ya tienes un método `setNext` para que le puedas pasar el siguiente nodo de la lista.

Tu constructor se debería limitar a hacer algo así:

```
Nodo<T>::Nodo()
    : dato{0}
    , next{nullptr}
{

}
```

Por cierto, no hay ninguna necesidad de convertir enteros a `int`

```
q->setDato(int(1500));
//         ~~~ Esto sobra
```

Como puedes ver en la siguiente línea, el código queda más legible sin conversiones innecesarias

```
q->setDato(1500);
```